# Fetch never returns data when msw (Mock Service Worker) intercepts request

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library, msw

I am currently using next/jest to setup my environment, with msw and @testing@library/react. My test looks like:

```
import { TestComponent } from '../../../components/TestComponent'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

test('Test TestComponent', function () {
  const wrap = render(<TestComponent />)
  expect(wrap.container.childElementCount).toBe(2)
})
```

My jest.config.js looks like:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
})

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test_utils/setup-env.js'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

My setup-env.js looks like this:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { server } from './server.js'

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())
```

My component looks something like this...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useSWRFetch } from '../../../hooks'

export const TestComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const dataInfo = useSWRFetch({
    endpoint: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/v1/endpoint`,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataInfo) {
      setDomains(dataInfo.data)
    }
  }, [dataInfo])
  return (
    <>
        {data &&
          data.map((item, idx) => (
                  <div>
                    <p>{item.count | 0}</p>
                    <p>Job</p>
                  </div>
          ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

When I run my test however I get the following error...

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

However when I value of dataInfo.data it is always undefined.

I have a fetcher function which SWR uses that looks like the following:

```
async function fetcher(...args) {
  console.log("BEFORE REQUEST")
  const url = args[0]
  const token = args[1]
  const method = args.length > 2 ? args[2] : 'GET'
  const body = args.length > 3 ? { body: JSON.stringify(args[3]) } : {}
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: method,

    headers:
      method != 'GET'
        ? {
            Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        : {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
    ...body,
  })

  console.log("AFTER REQUEST")

  if (!res.ok) {
    const error = new Error('An error occurred while fetching the data.')
    // Attach extra info to the error object.
    error.info = await res.json()
    error.status = res.status
    throw error
  }

  return res.json()
}

function useSWRFetch({ endpoint, token, options = null, condition=true }) {
  const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(token && condition ? [endpoint, token] : null, fetcher, options)

  return {
    mutate: mutate,
    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    error: error,
  }
}
```

However it never reaches the second console, AFTER REQUEST when the request is intercepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [React Jest tests failing with MSW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65464266/react-jest-tests-failing-with-msw) the answer is probably the same:

You need to make sure that your tests are waiting for things to unwrap. If you're not awaiting something to happen, your test-suite will not execute properly.

Try implementing a loading-state and then:

```js
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText("Loading ..."))
```

As this might be considered "bad practice" you can also do the opposite which would be waiting for something to appear:

```js
await screen.findByText('The text you are waiting for');
```

I'd also like to point out that @kettanaito 's answer helped me a lot to find a good polyfill for `vitest`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As per the error message, you haven't polyfilled `fetch` in your tests. Node.js doesn't have the `fetch` function as it's a browser-only API. If you're testing code that uses `fetch` (your `fetcher` does), you need to polyfill that function always. This is often done by frameworks like Create React App, but if you're using a custom setup you have to do that manually.

I recommend using [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch):

```js
// setup-env.js
import 'whatwg-fetch'

// ...the rest of your test setup
```

Once `fetch` is polyfilled, Jest will be able to run your tests and you will get the mocked response back.

Comment: I added whatwg-fetch, however although it is intercpeted it still did not return the response

Comment: You clearly haven't. Otherwise "fetch" would not be undefined. Check how you're including `whatwg-fetch` and whether you're doing that correctly. `typeof fetch` in your test must _not_ return `undefined`. The response is not returned because your test cannot make a request to begin with.

Comment: I am running into the same problem myself. I am importing `whatwg-fetch` in my test setup using Vitest (not Jest) with MSW and I can see that `fetch` is defined. However, when the `fetch` instruction is evaluated in test, MSW never seems to return a response back even though I have provided an interceptor. I have also tried the `cross-fetch` polyfill and that did not work either. I am using Node v16.20.2 and I have no idea how to go about debugging the issue further. Also, upgrading to Node v18+ is not an option for me unfortunately :(

Comment: A bit more detail to inject after digging in more deeply. So I do see that I get a `Response` back after performing the `fetch` call against my MSW server with the `whatwg-fetch` polyfill -- (however, the `cross-fetch` polyfill does *not* give me a response back).

The problem appears to be when I attempt to do `await response.json()` to retrieve the body data from the response. For reasons currently unbeknownst to me, that instruction never evaluates to completion and I cannot figure out why or how to debug the issue.

Comment: Did some more digging -- after wrapping my `await response.json()` in a `try/catch` block, I ended up discovering that a `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` exception was being thrown which explains why the instruction chokes. But I still do not understand how that is happening in test when I am using the same data in my local dev environment with no problem (i.e. using `vite`).